# How to fill an array with another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create clones of an element in an object and set new names for the clones.

```
class My_Obj{
 var $obj;
 var $obj_name;
 var clone;      //----int input to say how many clones are needed
 var clone_names;//----array input to make clone's name different from $obj
 function __construct( $args = '' ) {
   $defaults=array(
   /* codes to set up the default $obj */
  )
if ( $this->clone >0 ){
  for ( $i = 0; $i <= $this->clone; ++$i ){
   $clone_obj[$i]['name'] = /* need to loop through array $clone_name to fill this */

}
 }

/* other codes */
}
```

The $clone_names, for example, can be array('cat', 'dog', 'bird'). It doesn't matter which order as long as each clone get a name. I would like to learn how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand what you're asking. Please show example *input data* and expected *output data* instead.

Comment: It's highly recommended that you adopt the [PHP5 style of class property definition](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php). The PHP4 style `var` keyword is no longer used. Instead you should be declaring these as `public` or `private` properties.

Comment: I can't figure it out either. And you're missing some $ symbols too.

Comment: Please indent and format your code properly if you post it here, otherwise it looks a bit unfriendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to fill the array `$clone_obj` with values from `$clone_names` - up to the number of clones specified in `$clone`?

If that's the case, this may work (I've rewritten the sample class you used):

```
class My_Obj {
    public $clone = 0;          //----int input to say how many clones are needed
    public $clone_names = array();  //----array input to make clone's name different from $obj
    private $clone_obj = array();   // array to store cloned names in

    function __construct($args = '') {
        for ($i=0; $i<$this->clone; $i++) {
            // copy the name in "$clone_names" to "$clone_obj", if it exists
        $this->clone_obj[$i] = array();
            $this->clone_obj[$i]['name'] = (isset($this->clone_names[$i]) ? $this->clone_names[$i] : '');
        }
    }
}
```